# Haskell scraping with http-conduit problems

Tags: haskell

I've been trying to write my first "real" haskell program, which is intended to eventually scrape information about movies from pages of the form http://www.boxofficemojo.com/weekly/chart/?yr=2012&wk=52&p=.htm. The first step I made towards doing this was to create a function that was able to query the weekly information from between two dates. The code I came up with does not work, and the error message is a bit beyond my current haskell abilities.

The code:

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import Data.Time.Clock
import Data.Time.Calendar.WeekDate
import Data.Time.Calendar (Day, addDays, fromGregorian)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (runResourceT)

import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import qualified Data.ByteString as S


curDate :: IO Day
curDate = fmap utctDay getCurrentTime

dayToWkYr :: Day -> (S.ByteString, S.ByteString)
dayToWkYr day = (C.pack (show year), C.pack (show week))
                where (year, week, _) = toWeekDate day

mkDateList :: Day -> Day -> [Day] -> [Day]
mkDateList start end lst
    | start == end = lst
    | otherwise    = mkDateList (addWk start) end (start:lst)
    where addWk = addDays 7

getMovies' :: Manager -> [Day] -> [Response L.ByteString] -> [Response L.ByteString]
getMovies' manager (d:ds) results = runResourceT $ do
    let (year, week) = dayToWkYr d
    initreq <- parseUrl "http://boxofficemojo.com/weekly/chart/"
    let request = initreq { queryString = "?yr=" `S.append` year `S.append`
                                            "&wk=" `S.append` week}
    response <- httpLbs request manager
    getMovies' manager ds (response:results)

getMovies' _ [] results = results
```

The error:

```
scraper.hs:27:37:
    Couldn't match type `[]' with `IO'
    When using functional dependencies to combine
      Control.Monad.Trans.Control.MonadBaseControl [] [],
        arising from the dependency `m -> b'
        in the instance declaration in `Control.Monad.Trans.Control'
      Control.Monad.Trans.Control.MonadBaseControl IO [],
        arising from a use of `runResourceT' at scraper.hs:27:37-48
    In the expression: runResourceT
    In the expression:
      runResourceT
      $ do { let (year, week) = dayToWkYr d;
             initreq <- parseUrl "http://boxofficemojo.com/weekly/chart/";
             let request = ...;
             response <- httpLbs request manager;
             .... }

scraper.hs:33:5:
    Couldn't match type `[]'
                  with `Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.ResourceT []'
    Expected type: Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.ResourceT
                     [] (Response L.ByteString)
      Actual type: [Response L.ByteString]
    In the return type of a call of getMovies'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      getMovies' manager ds (response : results)
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `do { let (year, week) = dayToWkYr d;
            initreq <- parseUrl "http://boxofficemojo.com/weekly/chart/";
            let request = ...;
            response <- httpLbs request manager;
            .... }'
```

If anyone could shed any light on what I am doing wrong, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm by no means a haskell expert, but this is what I changed to make it compile.

The problem lies in the function getMovies'. 
First the return type should be IO [Response L.ByteString]. The second problem lies in your handling of the conduit Resource Monad, the function **runResourceT** returns whatever you have done in your conduit stream, which in your case should be the return value from **httpLbs request manager**. So you need to move the recursive call to **getMovies'** out from the Resource monad.

```
getMovies' :: Manager -> [Day] -> [Response L.ByteString] -> IO [Response L.ByteString]
getMovies' manager (d:ds) results = do
  response <- runResourceT $ do  -- we get the response here instead
    let (year, week) = dayToWkYr d
    initreq <- parseUrl "http://boxofficemojo.com/weekly/chart/"
    let request = initreq { queryString = "?yr=" `S.append` year `S.append`
                                            "&wk=" `S.append` week}
    httpLbs request manager
  getMovies' manager ds (response:results)

getMovies' _ [] results = return results -- wrap results in the IO monad.
```